# Excel Grouping by week with specific hour as start and end

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking to use a pivot table to display a data set with dates.  I would like to group the data by week, which I have been able to do through the pivot table, however, I have not been successful in doing this with reference to a specific start and end hour every week, which is what I need.

For example, my data starts on Wednesday, the 9th of March with a data point at 15:43, then there are more data points every few minutes leading up to the current day.  I would like to group this starting at 15:00 on Wednesday with each grouping running for one week, ending at 15:00 on the following Wednesday and continuing along this pattern up to the current day and into the future as the table is updated.

To illustrate this:  Start of Grouping: Wednesday, 09/03/17 15:00, end of grouping/start of next group Wednesday, 16/03/17 15:00.

Does anyone know if this can be done with or without pivot tables in Excel?  Help would be much appreciated since there does not seem to be a lot of info for this particular issue with respect to the specific hourly start and end time of a weekly group.

I am using Excel 2016 for Mac.

Comment: Did either of the answers below solve your issue? If so, please mark one of them as answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a helper column to your data table, this formula should help you get you on the right track:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done with PivotTables, using the Grouping function:

[image]

...but unfortunately the result is sorted alphabetically, not by date order:

[image]

It should be possible to write some code to sort these in the proper order using a Custom Sort Order, if this is the approach you want to take. Otherwise, Chris' approach is a good one.